# Understanding battery charger terminology

Tags: voltage, batteries, current, battery-charging

I've a few questions regarding this [charge management controller IC](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/22005b.pdf).

On page 11, section 3.0, they mention Charge Status Outputs (STAT1, STAT2) and Timer Enable and in section 4.3, page 14, they mention pre-conditioning.

What is the meaning of "pre-conditioning" and what is its purpose?

Also, what is the use of the STAT1, STAT2 and timer-enable pins? What status information will I be getting from the two pins? It isn't mentioned in the datasheet.

And what's the purpose of the Timer and Therm pins?

Comment: Have you taken the time to read the datasheet carefully? It goes in great detail to describe how it operates and even has a flowchart. As for preconditioning, that basically checks to see if the battery is ok before going into fast charge.

Comment: @Kartman, I did read the datasheet. But I am just beginning to learn this battery charge controller concept to work on a project. I have got the Eval board of this IC. So, starting to understand the terms before I test the Eval board. Could you please explain the terms? Also, thank you for helping with preconditioning. But why is it important? Any specific reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the meaning of "pre-conditioning" and what is its purpose? But why is it important? Any specific reason?

Depending on the chemistry, it may not be good to apply full charging current to a fully depleted battery as it may have a negative impact on battery's health and lifespan. So, starting from a lower current and increasing gradually is generally better. The "low-current start and heat up" process is called pre-conditioning.

> Also, what is the use of the STAT1, STAT2 and timer-enable pins? What status information will I be getting from the two pins? It isn't mentioned in the datasheet.

They *are* mentioned in the datasheet. Check the flow chart at p.13 and the table at p.17 for details. The STAT# outputs are basically there for indication (via LEDs for example) and can be used for interfacing with an MCU.

[image]

TE (Timer Enable) input is available on only MCP73834. It's basically a timer to stop charging to, probably, prevent overcharge or overtemperature. If you apply a logic low a timer starts right after charging is initiated. The duration is factory-programmed, so refer to table at p.29 for details:

[image]

HINT: Always read the datasheet carefully, and make use of the "search" function of your document reader.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding the STAT outputs, what status information they convey? Do they convey the battery voltage or the charging is happening? That was not clear for me. Also, could you please tell the purpose of the timer enable?

Comment: @Newbie check the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.